# Analysis of the stability of the system characterized by the transfer function - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, transfer-function

I also have a problem to solve in the field of "systems theory". I solved the mathematical part, but now I have to find a virtual method for analyzing the stability of the system characterized by the transfer function. Therefore, I chose matlab.

I need to graphically display the Nyquist diagram and the poles and zeros of the transfer function.

Transfer function:

[image]

The code for the Nyquist diagram is as follows:

```
num=[1 1]
den=[1 1 4 1 2]
G=tf(num,den)
plot(nyquist(G))
grid on
```

The code for representing the poles and zeros of the transfer function is as follows:

```
num=[1 1]
den=[1 1 4 1 2]
G=tf(num,den)
plot(pzmap(G))
grid on
```

How could I see on the same graph both functions or one below the other?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi! Did you do any research yourself on the internet? This is namely a pretty common thing to do with matlab. You can plot two lines in the in the same figure using the [hold on](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html) functionality. Plotting figures below each other can be done using [subplot](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html)

Comment: Of course, but it's not what I want...

Comment: "How could I see on the same graph both functions or one below the other?" Suggests you want a figure with two lines/plots plotted in either one or two subfigures. Maybe you can clarify further what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, now I think I know what you want. As feedback, could you next time include in the description that `nyquist()` and `pzmap` create their own figure. That's why it was not clear what the problem was.

Anyway from the `nyquist()` and `pzmap()` function you can obtain the necessary info in order to plot it in a different graph as stated in their respective documentations ([nyquist](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/nyquist.html), [pzmap](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/pzmap.html)). For `w` I selected a vector so that the whole nyquist shape is sufficiently visible.

```
num=[1 1];
den=[1 1 4 1 2];
G=tf(num,den);
w = linspace(-2*pi,2*pi,1e4);
[re,im] = nyquist(G,w);
[p,z] =pzmap(G);

figure();
plot(squeeze(re),squeeze(im));
hold on;
plot(real(p),imag(p),'*',real(z),imag(z),'o');
grid on
```

Resulting figure:

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's very good. Thank you very much. I don't know matlab very well and that's why I asked.